# Webview building up the memory in Android

Tags: android, keyboard, webview

In my hybrid Android application, on a `ListView` item click I'm loading a `WebView` by passing the `WebView` activity with the url to display in it. The user can come back to the earlier view by clicking back button.

But what is happening is after clicking on 3-4 `ListView` items, the app is becoming slow, which I think is because `WebView` activity is loaded again and again without deallocating it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the onDestroy() of the webview activity destroy the WebView as well. `myWebView.destroy();`